# How to edit a shared component from parent's HTML in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

**child.component.ts**

```
//ignoring all imports

@component({
   selector: 'app-child',
   template: './child.component.html'
})

import class ChildComponent {

   //logic not of use

   public isData: boolean = false;
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" [readonly]="isData">
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
//ignoring all imports
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

Here, I wanted to use the child component inside parent but I don't want the input field **readonly**, rather changing it inside child I want to change it inside parent so that my child component should not gets disturbed.

How would I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide some parameter in child component which turn on/off read only property - e.g.

child.component.html

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" [readonly]="isData || onlyForRead">
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input('onlyForRead') onlyForRead: boolean;
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child [onlyForRead]='false'></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query (get references) to all child components nested in the parent by using

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) dataItems: QueryList<ChildComponent>
```

or get reference to only 1:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) dataItem: ChildComponent;
```

Then you can subscribe and control the sate of each individual component from parent:

```
this.dataItem.isData = true // or false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with few simple steps:
In `Child-Component.ts` file:

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

@Input('isData') isData;
```

In parent-Component.html file:

```
<app-child isData="true"></app-child>
```